# Process Explorer Reports Processes with 2TB "virtual size" in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, virtual-memory, process-explorer

This screen snip of Process Explorer shows multiple processes with >2TB "virtual size":

[image]

This can't mean they are all using 2TB of virtual memory, so I'm wondering just what this means.

Comment: I see the same thing in Process Explorer V16.26 64-bit here on my Windows 10 machine. There is an explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030274/what-is-virtual-size-in-sysinternals-process-explorer .  I do not use the column and otherwise nothing is wrong here

Comment: Not fixed in Process Explorer 16.30 (new in the last 60 days)

Comment: I don't think the problem is with ProcessExplorer itself, I see the same thing using PowerShell's Get-Process command. I don't know how normal it is, found this thread looking for an answer on tracking processes using "Committed memory" since mind get in the 60GB range over a day without reboot.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the answer on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56909785/unreasonably-huge-process-virtual-memory-size-reported-by-process-explorer): it seems this is expected when applications are built to support what is called Control Flow Guard (CFG).

Answer (score 0):

Virtual size shows that application "thinks" that PC has 2TB of memory installed, and windows can allocate any address in this huge range when application tries to allocate some memory. This is done to decrease the chance of attacker to guess some function or data in memory, as OS shuffles things around in this big virtual range of memory.